# Is it true that Prophet Isa is not from the blood line of Adam?

Tags: prophet-isa, adam-and-eve, prophet-adam

Today I have a discussion with a Christian office colleague.  He said that Prophet Isa is not from the blood line of Adam. Because when husband and wife interact with each other then in the result the baby is born. But nobody touches Mariam (A.I), and Prophet Isa born by the power of Allah. So he said, Prophet Isa is not from the blood line of Adam. That's why Christians say that the Prophet Isa is the son of God.

My question is:  Is it true that Prophet Isa is not from the blood line of Adam?

Comment: That's a very strange thing for a Christian to say. I'm a lifelong Christian and I've never heard it, nor does it seem logically coherent to me.

Comment: [Hebrews 7:14](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nkjv/heb/7/1/t_bibles_1140014) states: "*For it is evident that our Lord arose from Judah …*", meaning that Jesus (Isa) looked Jewish. It is commonly accepted by all denominations that I'm aware of that he *was* Jewish. ¶
Ask your colleague where he got this idea from. I've never heard of it before.  If he can provide a specific Christian denomination that teaches it, or provide references for this belief, it would make an interesting question on Christianity.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is true, why don't they say adam and eve as son of Allah. Also that camel Allah showed as a sign from the rocks should also be daughter of Allah? Angles have no fathers they are also children of Allah?

In-fact by saying this they are disrespecting Allah and saying he cannot create something with his will. We cannot understand his power, he willed to show people hsi sign by making a women pregnant without a man, and he did. Its his power, this does not make that person his child.

And yes, he was from bloodline of Adam, the father of mankind. His mother maryan was his daughter, and issa is her son.

Comment: None of what you said can help to determine whether or not Jesus was a pure "miracle" or the progeniture of his only mother or both.

Comment: This is a fact we all know that maryan was pregnant and then issa was born, he was not like sent to him by any other way. SO definitely he was her son. And allah has no son. so...

Comment: I agree with Zia on this. "Fertilization begins with the spermatozoon contacting the cells surrounding the oocyte and ends with the mixing of the 23 male and 23 female chromosomes.5 [More about fertilization] The result is a single-cell embryo called a zygote,6 meaning "yoked or joined together,"7 and it is the first cell of the human body. " - Just an example, Allah only need to create one cell, and the other information is taken from Eve, which contains the genetic information of Adam too.

Comment: Subhanallah....

Comment: If you claim God created 1 cell, why not both ? Couldn't Mariam be the bearer of the miracle of God ?

Comment: In that case he would not be the son of maryam, and maryam would not have been pregnant, while we all know allah says many times in quran ISSA IBN MARYAN in many places including إِذْ قَالَتِ الْمَلَائِكَةُ يَا مَرْيَمُ إِنَّ اللَّهَ يُبَشِّرُكِ بِكَلِمَةٍ مِّنْهُ اسْمُهُ الْمَسِيحُ عِيسَى ابْنُ مَرْيَمَ وَجِيهًا فِي الدُّنْيَا وَالْآخِرَةِ وَمِنَ الْمُقَرَّبِينَ

Comment: He could still be the son of Maryam, didn't she bear him in her belly ? Why  couldn't he be entirely a miracle from God ? Or did you expect from him to be called the son of God ? Why do you and @Kilise claim God created one part and Mariam contributed to the other part ?

Comment: @cerberus23 I didn't claim that, I said it as an example and a possibility. To go any further would be speaking about ghayb (the unseen)

Comment: That's what bothers me, it's the speaking of the ghayb. And the answer like many in this place are speaking of the ghayb.

Comment: This verse should also be taken into consideration:  [3:59] إِنَّ مَثَلَ عِيسَىٰ عِندَ اللَّهِ كَمَثَلِ آدَمَ ۖ خَلَقَهُ مِن تُرَابٍ ثُمَّ قَالَ لَهُ كُن فَيَكُونُ

Comment: From tafsir ibn kasir(translation):
Therefore, He Who created Adam without a father or a mother is able to create `Isa, as well, without a father. If the claim is made that `Isa is Allah's son because he was created without a father, then the same claim befits Adam even more. However, since such a claim regarding Adam is obviously false, then making the same claim about `Isa is even more false.

Comment: Furthermore, by mentioning these facts, Allah emphasizes His ability, by creating Adam without a male or female, Hawa' from a male without a female, and `Isa from a mother without a father, compared to His creating the rest of creation from male and female.

Answer (score 1):

I understand what do you mean .

Yes He has the genetics of Adam because His mother is descendant from The father of human Adam

Answer (score -1):

thanks for allowing me to respond. I find the topic of great interest. In The Bible we find that JESUS was both human and divine. Human in that he was from David's bloodline and Divine in that he had no human Father. Isaiah the prophet declared him to be the "everlasting father" (9;6). It is interesting to note also that Jesus is called the "Word of God" (Revelation 19;13) and he is worshipped and obeyed whereas the scriptures are the "words" (plural) of God and to be followed.

Answer (score -4):

With both the Holy Bible and the Holy Quran as my witnesses.
Isa al-Masih is from the bloodline of Adam through his Mother Maryam, but unlike natural sons of Man(Adam), Isa al-Masih had no physical father, so Allah gave him his Y Chromosome, thus He is a son of Man and a son of Allah, even though he was not begotten by Allah, also like Allah, Isa al-Masih didn't beget, nor was he begotten. The term "only begotten" in the New Testament is a mistranslation of monogenes meaning unique. Isa al-Masih is Allah's Eternal Word made flesh. Note: the term Son of Man in Hebrew simply means Human and thus Son of God also means Divine, Hence Isa al-Masih being both fully Human and fully Divine, but this also means because he is a human, he shouldn't be worshipped even though he is also divine. Do You don't worship the Holy Quran as Allah just because it is Allah's Eternal Word, do you? No. So why then should Isa Al-Masih be worshipped? He shouldn't be worshipped as Allah, but rather He is to be venerated as the Eternal Word made flesh. The Eternal Word of Allah is al-Hadi, al-Haqq, and al-Hayy, for no goes to Allah except by obeying His Eternal Word.